# SQL Server - Sum entire column AND Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I had the following table in SQL Server:

```
grp:     val:     criteria:
a        1        1
a        1        1
b        1        1
b        1        1
b        1        1
c        1        1
c        1        1
c        1        1
d        1        1
```

Now what I want is to get an output which would basically be:

```
Select grp, val / [sum(val) for all records] grouped by grp where criteria = 1
```

So, given the following is true:

```
Sum of all values = 9
Sum of values in grp(a) = 2
Sum of values in grp(b) = 3
Sum of values in grp(c) = 3
Sum of values in grp(d) = 1
```

The output would be as follows:

```
grp:     calc:    
a        2/9        
b        3/9        
c        3/9        
d        1/9
```

What would my SQL have to look like??

Thanks!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this which uses [`sum() over()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
select distinct grp,
  sum(val) over(partition by grp)
    / (sum(val) over(partition by criteria)*1.0) Total
from yourtable 
where criteria = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efa1f/12)

The result is:

```
| GRP |          TOTAL |
------------------------
|   a | 0.222222222222 |
|   b | 0.333333333333 |
|   c | 0.333333333333 |
|   d | 0.111111111111 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @bluefeet's response -- this is just a little more of a database-independent approach (should work with most RDBMS):

```
select distinct
  grp,
  sum(val)/cast(total as decimal)
from yourtable 
cross join 
(
  select SUM(val) as total 
  from yourtable
) sumtable
where criteria = 1
GROUP BY grp, total
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9d2b/1).

Comment: Thanks @sgedded! - Definitely not something I would have thought of doing and a great addition to my arsenal!! Thanks!